# Haskell: Parse CSV file into list of lists of floats

Tags: csv, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to read a csv file and make a list of lists of floats and I get 'IO' compiler error.  Ubuntu 18.04 with GHCI 8.0.2.   CSV file looks like this:

```
2,112,66,22,0,25.0,0.307,24,0
3,113,44,13,0,22.4,0.140,22,0
```

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "data/pima.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        --Right v -> V.forM_ v ( printMyStuff ) --this works
        Right v -> V.concatMap v makeFloatList --'IO' compile fail


printMyStuff [v1 :: Float, v2 :: Float, v3 :: Float,
           v4 :: Float, v5 :: Float, v6 :: Float,
           v7 :: Float, v8 :: Float, v9 :: Float] =
    putStrLn ( show v1 ++ ", " ++ show v2 ++ ", " ++ show v3 ++
         ", " ++ show v4 ++ ", " ++ show v5 ++ ", " ++ show v6 ++
         ", " ++ show v7 ++ ", " ++ show v8 ++ ", " ++ show v9)

makeFloatList [v1 :: Float, v2 :: Float, v3 :: Float,
           v4 :: Float, v5 :: Float, v6 :: Float,
           v7 :: Float, v8 :: Float, v9 :: Float] =
                                     [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9]
```

and the (first) error message is:

```
CSVFloat.hs:11:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘V.Vector’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO ()
        Actual type: V.Vector ()
    • In the expression: V.concatMap v makeFloatList
      In a case alternative: Right v -> V.concatMap v makeFloatList
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case decode NoHeader csvData of
          Left err -> putStrLn err
          Right v -> V.concatMap v makeFloatList
   |
11 |         Right v -> V.concatMap v makeFloatList --'IO' compile fail
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: And what is the point of `makeFloatList`? You typed a lot of code that takes a list of exactly nine floats and returns that exact same list.

Comment: @user266782, I took the liberty of adding a copy of the error message that I saw when compiling your program.  If the error you got was different, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand side of the case:

```
Right v -> ...
```

needs to be an IO action that not only converts `v` to the list of type `[[Float]]` that you want, but also *uses* the result somehow in some IO (the same way your first, successful attempt tried to print it out).

Converting `v` to a `[[Float]]` is actually pretty easy.  You don't need `V.concatMap` or `makeFloatList`.  Instead, using `V.toList` to convert it to a list of rows, if you give it the right type signature, the `decode` function will "figure out" that you want each row to be a list of floats.  So, you can just write:

```
Right v -> do let mylist = V.toList v :: [[Float]]
              ...
```

but you still have to decide what to do with `mylist`.  Printing it would be an option:

```
Right v -> do let mylist = V.toList v :: [[Float]]
              print v
```

giving:

```
> main
[[2.0,112.0,66.0,22.0,0.0,25.0,0.307,24.0,0.0],
 [3.0,113.0,44.0,13.0,0.0,22.4,0.14,22.0,0.0]]
>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great.  I'll be sure to post the error text next time.